# Multiple Segues From AppDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I'm trying to respond to a UNNotificationAction and segue into a detailed view which is at the third layer from the initial view controller.

This is what the layout looks like:

[image: Generic segue layout]

I'd like it to perform segue A then segue B, triggered from userNotificationCenter_didReceive, so far I have this working but it only performs segue A to View Controller 2, I have been unsuccessful in attempts to trigger the next segue.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    if let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "1") as? ViewController1 {
        viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "A", sender: nil)
        //It works this far, and loads the View Controller 2
        //Next I need to initiate segue B, to move to View Controller 3
    } 
    completionHandler()
}
```

If successful it would be possible for the user to move back to view 2 then view 1 as though they had passed by them on the way to view 3.

Thanks

---

### My Solution

In `AppDelegate`

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // guard **expected response** else { return }
    
    if let vc1 = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "1") as? ViewController1 {
        vc1.shouldSegueToVC3 = true
        vc1.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVC2", sender: nil)
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

`ViewController1` class

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    
    var shouldSegueToVC3: Bool = false
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        
        if shouldSegueToVC3,
           let vc2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            vc2.shouldSegueToVC3 = true
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewController2` class

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    
    var shouldSegueToVC3: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if shouldSegueToVC3 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToVC3", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Sequence of events**

`ViewController1` has it's flag `shouldSegueToVC3` set to `true`, then the segue to `ViewController2` is called. In `prepare(for segue:)` `ViewController2` has it's own `shouldSegueToVC3` set to true. When `ViewController2` appears, if that flag is true then it segues to `ViewController3`.

This uses the storyboard segues, but instantiating the view controllers programatically and pushing them would be cleaner.

Comment: Have you tried in viewDidLoad() method for initiating segue "B" in viewController "2"? Or what you have done for segue "B" ?

Comment: Yes, one attempt involved a Bool in VC1 that if true set a bool in VC2 (using prepareForSegue) that if true, triggered the segue to VC3. I set the Bool in VC1 for the userNotificationCenter above, however it never seemed to run ViewDidLoad in VC2

Comment: Ok. Did you check the Bool in ViewDidLoad() in VC1?

Comment: If you did the check in viewDidLoad() then shift the code from viewDidLoad() to viewDidAppear(). Because viewDidLoad() is for loading the View. Redirect to another viewController, best approach is wait for the view fully loaded then navigation to other viewController.

Comment: Good point, it wasn't set to true. I was ignoring the fact it segued through a navigation controller, and needed to get the destination from destination.viewControllers.first and set the bool in that! Got it working thanks!

Comment: Ok that's great. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with a `UINavigationController`. You asked for a solution using segues but a `segue` is just the interface-builder version of `push`. Programmers use segues because they require less work but they have their restrictions, like this. Clearly your UI requires an extra level of navigation complexity so I would recommend using a navigation controller (which you may already have set up).

```
let firstViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as! FirstViewController
let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
var controllers = navigationController?.viewControllers

controllers?.append(firstViewController)
controllers?.append(secondViewController)

if let controllers = controllers {
    navigationController?.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
}
```

This will create one animation as if the user pushed directly to the second view controller but will pop to the first view controller when the user navigates backward.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much more concise method